# Undefined behaviour on deleting a node in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, c99, doubly-linked-list

So I am trying to delete a node in a doubly linked list, given only a pointer to the node. This is my code:

```
void deleteNode(Node* node) {
    if(node == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    
    if(node->next != NULL) {
         node->next->prev = node->prev;
    }
    if(node->prev != NULL) {
         node->prev->next = node->next;
    }

    node->next = NULL; node->prev = NULL;
    free(node);
    node = NULL;
}
```

When I try to delete a single node, the head pointer is still not NULL. Instead if I try to print the key, it's giving some random value. What might be causing this behaviour? Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Hint: if you have `int make7(int x) {x=7;}` and then you write in main `int i=5; make7(i);` what value is stored in `i`?

Comment: What is the purpose of `node = NULL`?  Do you expect that line of code to make any difference at all?  Consider `void foo(int x) { ...; x = 0; }`

Answer (score 2):

```
node = NULL;
```

does nothing. `node` is a local variable and it stops to exist when the function returns.

```
void deleteNode(Node **node) 
{
    if(node && *node) 
    {
        if((*node)->next) (*node)->next->prev = (*node)->prev;
        if((*node)->prev) (*node)->prev->next = (*node)->next;

        free(*node);
        *node = NULL;
    }    
}
```

As you see the code can be reduced to just few lines.